# design bandpass filter in specific range

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

let say that we have signal with sampling frequency  100 hertz,i want to design FIR  filter so that  cut all frequency that are outsize of frequency range  15-20,if we convert it to the normalized frequency we will get  15/50=0.3   and 0.4,i know that for example i can use butter to design filter,for example like there 
http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~gmirchan/classes/EE275/Lab5.pdf

but  could  you help me please to  design bandpass filter in matlab?let say we have some signal s(t),

this command

```
[b a] = butter(2, 400/(fs/2));
```

designs a second order Butterworth filter with cutoff frequency  400 and then this command

```
y = filter(b,a,swn);
```

filters given signal, but instead of one cut-off frequency, I need range 15-20, so how can I apply bandpass filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use that very same function [`butter()`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/ref/butter.html) to design bandpass filters as well, simply by supplying a vector of cutoff frequencies instead of a scalar:

```
% filter design
fs = 100;
f1 = 15;
f2 = 20;

% normalized frequency
w1 = f1 / (fs/2);
w2 = f2 / (fs/2);

% second-order butterworth
[b, a] = butter(2, [w1 w2]);

% filtering
x = randn(1, 10000);
y = filter(b, a, x);
```

In your question, you're talking about the need for an FIR filter. However, a Butterworth filter has an infinite impulse response, as you can see from the fact that the function `butter()` returns a vector `a` with more than one element.

Comment: so which filter could i use?also could you please show me  how to apply  vector  of cutoff frequencies

Comment: @datodatuashvili see my updated answer. There is nothing wrong with the Butterworth filter, but if you really need FIR filters, please have a look at the [filter design documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/digital-filter-design.html), I cannot tell you which one to choose since it depends on a lot of additional circumstances.